# Jersey @GET method not working with 2 Path Params

Tags: java, rest, jersey

in my Jersey REST interface, there are two methods (among others):

```
@GET
@Path("{scenarioId}/instance")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public Response getScenarioInstances(
        @Context UriInfo uri,
        @PathParam("scenarioId") int scenarioId,
        @QueryParam("filter") String filterString) {
    // code here
    return Response.ok(result.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

and

```
@GET
@Path("{scenarioId}/instance/{instanceId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getScenarioInstance(
        @Context UriInfo uri,
        @PathParam("scenarioId") int scenarioId,
        @PathParam("instanceId") int instanceId) {
    // code here
    return Response.ok(result.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

A GET request via Postman to, say, /2/instance, calls the first method and results in a JSON object containing all instances.

A GET request to e.g. /2/instance/2 however does not call the second method, and results in a 404 error.

Am I missing something in the second method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was, that the REST interface was distributed over multiple classes, and there was another class that had a @Path(".../{scenarioId}/instance/{instanceId}) annotation. 
I moved the method there, and it was called. Apparently this causes a conflict, even thought there was no @GET method declared for this path directly in this class.

In retrospect, I probably should have added that detail to the question.